# Erro desconhecido: "null" ao executar um HTTPPost com Parâmetros

Tags: android, node.js, http, post, logcat

## Explicação:

Eu possuo um simples aplicativo Android, e também um servidor NodeJS. Tenho as seguintes permissões no `AndroidManifest.xml` da minha aplicação:

```xml
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Estou tentando realizar um HTTP Post e uma URL Local, mas isso gera um erro desconhecido:`null`, ao executar o HTTP Post. Por isso não tenho como saber o que está acontecendo.

Já verifiquei o LogCat mas nada de erros, apenas esse erro `null` da minha Exception está aparecendo.

Aqui está o código do HTTP Post:

```java
HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://192.168.25.32:8080/signup");
HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams(); //eu estava usando Params, agora uso Pairs
List<NameValuePair> pairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", "Teste2"));
pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", "testezin@email.com"));
pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("country", "Brazil"));
pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("user", "teste"));
pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pass", "123456"));
post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(pairs));            
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(post); //aqui vai para a Exception
```

## Pergunta:

O que estou fazendo de errado ? Como posso resolver este problema ?

Também gostaria de saber porque esse erro está sendo gerado.

## Observação:

Quando acessando `http://192.168.25.32:8080/signup` eu tenho uma html form de cadastro funcionando certinho, daí da pra saber que meu servidor NodeJS está comunicando certinho, e funcionando, por isso tenho certeza que o erro está no Android.

Comment: Tente deixar de usaro IP para usar uma URL

Comment: Impossível. É um endereço da rede local.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. A url está acessivel no browser do device? Acredito que não seja isso, pois isso é mais comum quando usamos localhost que não é reconhecido pelo device, mesmo o AVD.
2. Você está usando uma thread única para fazer o Post? Pelo seu código não podemos saber isso, mas é uma possível resposta.

Tente usar [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html):

```
new TheTask().execute("http://192.168.25.32/signup");
```

E a classe ficaria algo parecido com isso:

```
class TheTask extends AsyncTask<String,String,String>
    {

@Override
protected String onPostExecute(Void result) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    // update textview here
    textView.setText("Server message is "+result);
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPreExecute();
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
     try
        {
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost method = new HttpPost(params[0]);
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(method);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            if(entity != null){
                return EntityUtils.toString(entity);
            }
            else{
                return "No string.";
            }
         }
         catch(Exception e){
             return "Network problem";
         }

}
}
```

Comment: Sim, está acessando normal no Browser do device. Porém no código o HTTP Post não funciona e não me diz o erro, só avisa "null" vou tentar usar uma Thread pra fazer o post, pois eu estou fazendo direto no onCreate da Activity

Comment: Com este código aí, não funciona. o método onPostExecute não existe no AsyncTask pelo jeito pois o eclipse avisa: `The method onPostExecute(Void) of type TheTask must override or implement a supertype method`

Comment: @PauloRoberto Tente alterar a classe estendendo para `AsyncTask<String, Void, String>` e o método para `onPostExecute(String result)`.

Comment: Cara utilizando essa `AsyncTask` funcionou! eu realizei umas alterações, como por exemplo retirei o `@Override` da `onPostExecute(Void result)` e mudei para `String result` o parametro mas isso foi só pra poder compilar, o problema era que eu não estava utilizando uma Tarefa(task) separada da principal para realizar o HTTP Post! eu nem imaginava que precisava ser feito em uma task separada pra funcionar :) agora está tudo ok aqui cara, obrigado!

Comment: Mas eu gostaria de saber como faço pro método onPostExecute funcionar...

Comment: Dexa quieto já consegui, mesmo assim obrigado ! :)

Comment: Achei outro problema, kkkk, só funciona a primera vez a Task, tem que abrir e fechar denovo a atividade pra tentar denovo

Comment: @PauloRoberto, desculpe não passar um código completo, pois estava sem tempo. Fico feliz que tenha conseguido resolver o problema. Se quiser posso colocar mais informações sobre "assincronicidade" no android.

Comment: Eu gostaria que você colocasse informações sobre como executar novamente uma `AsyncTask` sem ter que reniciar a Activity

Answer (score 1):

Ao meu ver seu código está correto, mas os códigos que fiz eu nunca coloquei a porta junto ao ip, tente remover a porta que você adicionou a url e acesse somente pelo ip e o /signup da seguinte forma:

```
HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://192.168.25.32/signup");
```

depois diga se funcionou.

Abraços.

Comment: Mas deste modo a porta a ser acessada será a 80 por padrão e a porta que meu servidor está escutando é a 8080

Comment: Mas sim, eu testei outro post no meu servidor apache que está na porta 80 e continuo com o mesmo erro desconhecido `null`